# Cannot initialize a contract instance in constructor using assembly

Tags: assembly, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to develop myself on inline-assembly. There are two contracts: CryptoDevs and Whitelist. In the assembly, i copied the whole code of whitelist contract instance into cryptodevs memory and I do not know whether it worked. What I am trying to achieve is to initalize the contract instance and get the value of the maxWhitelistedAddresses value in the whitelist contract using inline-assembly. Thanks in advance.

```
contract CryptoDevs {

   // Whitelist contract instance
    Whitelist whitelist;

    // Number of tokens reserved for whitelisted members
    uint256 public reservedTokens;
    uint256 public reservedTokensClaimed = 0;


    /**
      * @dev ERC721 constructor takes in a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
      * name in our case is `Crypto Devs` and symbol is `CD`.
      * Constructor for Crypto Devs takes in the baseURI to set _baseTokenURI for the collection.
      * It also initializes an instance of whitelist interface.
      */
constructor (address whitelistContract) ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD") {
        assembly {
            // load free memory pointer
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            // retrieve the size of the code
            let size := extcodesize(whitelistContract)
            mstore(ptr, size)
            // copy the code of whitelist contract
            extcodecopy(whitelistContract, add(ptr, 0x20), 0, size)
            // get the code from memory
            let code := mload(0x40)
            // store the code in storage
            sstore(0x02, code)
        }
    }
```

and this is the original code I am trying to turn into assembly.

```
contract CryptoDevs {

    // Whitelist contract instance
    Whitelist whitelist;

    // Number of tokens reserved for whitelisted members
    uint256 public reservedTokens;
    uint256 public reservedTokensClaimed = 0;

    /**
      * @dev ERC721 constructor takes in a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
      * name in our case is `Crypto Devs` and symbol is `CD`.
      * Constructor for Crypto Devs takes in the baseURI to set _baseTokenURI for the collection.
      * It also initializes an instance of whitelist interface.
      */
    constructor (address whitelistContract) ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD") {
        whitelist = Whitelist(whitelistContract);
        reservedTokens = whitelist.maxWhitelistedAddresses();
    }
```